# How to do center alignment in multirow in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I have problem with center alignment in Lyx. You can see this on the screen.

[image]
Is it possible to fix it somehow in the Lyx where I have only limited options to edit code?

Thank you
Petr

Comment: Just for your information, questions regarding LyX are better suited for TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge all of the cells (0,3) to (0,6), I'm using LyX version 2.1.3.

To merge all of the cells you'll need to delete the text, unmerge, then re-merge and add the text back in.

[image: Table in Lyx.]
[image: Table rendered.]